# How to exclude specific route in PWA with vue cli config? 

Tags: javascript, caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, vue-cli

I have two different projects (or repo) on the server. one of them is wroten with vue.js (SPA) and another is created by static site generator ([mkdoc](https://www.mkdocs.org/)).

then I add PWA to my SPA project (from [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html#example-configuration)) and a strange thing happened. in my project, I navigate to example.com/**help** but it shown a 404 page while **/help** route is for my mddoc project!

[image: 404 page]

in other words:

```
SPA Project domain: example.com
mkdoc Project domain: example.com/help
```

so I searched on the web and thought about this problem and I realized why this problem happens!

I think that's because of the service worker in PWA! the service worker cached all the files and assets of the project.

now I think to solve this problem I should prevent cache the **/help** route! but I couldn't understand how to [config](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-webpack-plugin.GenerateSW#GenerateSW) PWA in `vue.config.js` [vue cli](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-webpack-plugin.GenerateSW#GenerateSW).

really I don't know that can we exclude one route and prevent to cache with the service worker or not!?

how can I fix this problem!?

**vue.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/',

  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: `
            @import "@/assets/styles/_boot.scss";
          `
      }
    }
  },

  pwa: {
    name: "app",
    themeColor: "#004581",
    msTileColor: "white",
    appleMobileWebAppCapable: "yes",
    appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: "white",

    iconPaths: {
      favicon32: 'img/icons/favicon-32x32.png',
      favicon16: 'img/icons/favicon-16x16.png',
      appleTouchIcon: 'img/icons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png',
      maskIcon: 'img/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg',
      msTileImage: 'img/icons/mstile-144x144.png',
    },

    // configure the workbox plugin
    workboxPluginMode: "GenerateSW",
    workboxOptions: {
      importWorkboxFrom: "local",
      navigateFallback: "/",

      ignoreUrlParametersMatching: [/help*/],

      // Do not precache images
      exclude: [/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/],

      // Define runtime caching rules
      runtimeCaching: [
        {
          // Match any request that ends with .png, .jpg, .jpeg or .svg.
          urlPattern: /\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,

          // Apply a cache-first strategy.
          handler: "CacheFirst",

          options: {
            // Use a custom cache name.
            cacheName: "images",

            // Only cache 10 images.
            expiration: {
              maxEntries: 10
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

**registerServiceWorker.js**

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready() {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n' +
          'For more details, visit https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-pwa'
      );
    },
    registered() {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.');
    },
    cached() {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.');
    },
    updatefound() {
      console.log('New content is downloading.');
    },
    updated() {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
    },
    offline() {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.');
    },
    error(error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I think if you want to use PWA in Vue.js it is recommended to use Nuxt.js ( https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/ )

Answer (score 4):

If you want to exclude specific route or routes from service worker you should add navigateFallbackDenylist to workboxOptions.

```
navigateFallbackDenylist: [/help*/],
```